# Set up SharePoint libraries as a single network drive with multiple libraries inside

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, file, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

Is it possible to add multiple SharePoint libraries as a single network drive?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You could point it directly to a site but the users would see all the lists/libraries, even the system-related ones in the site (which they have access to and are required for basic SharePoint functionality to work).

You could create something that acts like it thought by using one library with multiple root folders with unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Zee Drive (a commercial tool) you can [map multiple document libraries, including from different sites, under a single network drive](https://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/).